# Problem with bar graphs

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, bar-chart, nodes-near-coords

I need to do a graph with horizontal bars, that give the period of plantation of each Field i, i=1,...,10.
I have the following code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,fleqn]{article}

\usepackage{a4wide}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[dvips]{epsfig}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm}
\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
\usepackage{fancybox}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{supertabular}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[usenames]{color}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[usenames]{color}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage{pgfplots}


\usepackage{tikz,tkz-euclide}
\usetkzobj{all}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usetikzlibrary{quotes,angles}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,shadings}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\usepgfplotslibrary{polar}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}

\usepackage{subfigure}

\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.3}  %1.6 = double line spacing
\newcommand{\Sum}{\sum\limits_}
\newtheorem{proposition}{Proposition}

% Set A4 size (very important because the default size is wider)
\paperwidth=8.3in
\paperheight=11.7in

\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\newlistcommand}{mm}
 {
  \NewDocumentCommand{#1}{m}
   {
    \clist_set:Nn \l_xaero_args_clist { ##1 }
    #2
   }
 }
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\argx}{m}
 {
  \clist_item:Nn \l_xaero_args_clist { #1 }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\newlistcommand{\graficobarras}{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}
  \pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}
    \begin{axis}[
        xmin=-2,xmax=29,
        tickwidth         = 5pt,
        ymax=11,
        width=15cm,
        height=10cm,
        axis y line=left,
        axis x line=bottom,
        ymin=0,
        xmajorgrids=true,
            nodes near coords,
        xlabel={Days},
        xticklabels={-2,0,2,4,...,30},
        ytick={1,2,...,10,12},
        yticklabels={Field 1,Field 2,Field 3,Field 4,Field 5,Field 6,Field 7,Field 8,
             Field 9,Field 10,}
        ]
      \filldraw[blue!40,draw=black] ([yshift=-2.5mm,xshift=-0.85cm]\argx{1},1) rectangle
               ([yshift=2.5mm,xshift=-0.85cm]\argx{2},1)node[right,yshift=-2.5mm,text=black]{\argx{21}};               
       \filldraw[blue!40,draw=black] ([yshift=-2.5mm,xshift=-0.85cm]\argx{3},2) rectangle
               ([yshift=2.5mm,xshift=-0.85cm]\argx{4},2)node[right,yshift=-2.5mm,text=black]{\argx{22}};               
       \filldraw[blue!40,draw=black] ([yshift=-2.5mm,xshift=-0.85cm]\argx{5},3) rectangle
               ([yshift=2.5mm,xshift=-0.85cm]\argx{6},3)node[right,yshift=-2.5mm,text=black]{\argx{23}};               
       \filldraw[blue!40,draw=black] ([yshift=-2.5mm,xshift=-0.85cm]\argx{7},4) rectangle
               ([yshift=2.5mm,xshift=-0.85cm]\argx{8},4)node[right,yshift=-2.5mm,text=black]{\argx{24}};               
       \filldraw[blue!40,draw=black] ([yshift=-2.5mm,xshift=-0.85cm]\argx{9},5) rectangle
               ([yshift=2.5mm,xshift=-0.85cm]\argx{10},5)node[right,yshift=-2.5mm,text=black]{\argx{25}};               
       \filldraw[blue!40,draw=black] ([yshift=-2.5mm,xshift=-0.85cm]\argx{11},6) rectangle
               ([yshift=2.5mm,xshift=-0.85cm]\argx{12},6)node[right,yshift=-2.5mm,text=black]{\argx{26}};               
       \filldraw[blue!40,draw=black] ([yshift=-2.5mm,xshift=-0.85cm]\argx{13},7) rectangle
               ([yshift=2.5mm,xshift=-0.85cm]\argx{14},7)node[right,yshift=-2.5mm,text=black]{\argx{27}};               
       \filldraw[blue!40,draw=black] ([yshift=-2.5mm,xshift=-0.85cm]\argx{15},8) rectangle
               ([yshift=2.5mm,xshift=-0.85cm]\argx{16},8)node[right,yshift=-2.5mm,text=black]{\argx{28}};               
       \filldraw[blue!40,draw=black] ([yshift=-2.5mm,xshift=-0.85cm]\argx{17},9) rectangle
               ([yshift=2.5mm,xshift=-0.85cm]\argx{18},9)node[right,yshift=-2.5mm,text=black]{\argx{29}};               
       \filldraw[blue!40,draw=black] ([yshift=-2.5mm,xshift=-0.85cm]\argx{19},10) rectangle
               ([yshift=2.5mm,xshift=-0.85cm]\argx{20},10)node[right,yshift=-2.5mm,text=black]{\argx{30}};
    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
}

\allowdisplaybreaks[1] %to allow automatic page breaks for formulas written with \alignat


\begin{document}

\graficobarras{1,7,10,17,2,9,25,30,16,22,24,30,7,16,5,24,23,30,18,24,9.87,11.32,10.67,11.39,14.44,13.70,10.65,7.07,14.32,11.32}

\end{document}
```

Each field has a planting period.
My problem is when I need to insert the number at right of last bar. Don't appear. I wouldn't to increase the parameter "xmax" to 31, because the grid also increase. There is a way to increase te size the figure, without to cut the nodes numbers?
This code generates the following picture:
[image]
Best regards.

Comment: Could you turn your code into a complete example that we can compile without any modifications? `\argx` and `\graficobarras` are not defined by default. Also, note that you can edit your question, so please add the image to the question, instead of posting it in an answer.

Comment: That said, add `clip=false` to the `axis` options.

Comment: Yes, I have done this modification, so you can to compile this figure.

Answer (score 2):

Simply add `clip=false` to the options of the `axis` in the definition of `\graficobarras`.

By default any paths, nodes etc. created by normal TikZ macros like `\filldraw` are clipped if they extend outside the axis limits. `clip=false` turns off that behaviour.

Unrelated note: you could tidy up the preamble a bit, you're loading several packages multiple times, which is unnecessary. Note also that the `a4wide` package is considered deprecated, it would be better to use the features of the `geometry` package.